# Is it possible to add side data "spherical: equirectangular" with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to add side data by ffmpeg?

```
Side data:
      stereo3d: side by side
      spherical: equirectangular
```

These values present in good videos, and miss from some of my videos. Videos already in 3D SBS format, no need to remap or convert it, just add these values to the stream.

I can add stereo3d by

```
ffmpeg ..... -metadata:s:v stereo_mode=left_right
```

parameters, but cannot figure out how to add the "spherical" value.
ffmpeg

Answer (score -1):

yes using the following command, one can preserve the side data using ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i testVideo.mp4 -c:a aac -strict unofficial spherical.mp4

Comment: Hi Ajay. I don't want to preserve (nothing to preserve), I need to add to fix it.  
Successfully fixed with Google's old spatialmedia py script (but not with ffmpeg). So now not really importand, but the question is still open.